# How to prevent default Shortcut alt+b by Firefox and IE via JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shortcut

I need to implement a shortcut alt+b, calling a function. My problem is, that everytime i press this shortcut, a Firefox and an IE open a Menu-Bar "Edit". Is there any solution to prevent this default behavior? Or maybe it is possible to close this menu-bar after calling a function?

What i have tried but without success

```
     $(document).keydown(function(e) {

         if (e.keyCode == 18 || e.which==18)
         {
            e.preventDefault(); 
         }           
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will only run the `console.log()` if you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Replace the console with anything you want.

```js
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
  if(event.altKey && event.keyCode == 66) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    console.log("Hey! alt+B event captured!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried this out, but no success. i tried to debug a .js file and i got this... https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwcxB.jpg                                                                  KeyCode is 18 (ALT)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

    // check for alt+b
    if (e.keyCode == 66 && e.altKey === true) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

You need to check the press of `b`, not `alt`.

Comment: i tried this out, but no success. i tried to debug a .js file and i got this... https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwcxB.jpg                                                                  KeyCode is 18 (ALT)

Comment: Can you make a live example? For instance using JSFiddle.